# Database Error : Vendor 20

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I'm connecting with database it was showing following error

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 20
```

I think it was due to problem with my classpath i tried to fix it but not succeeded
my classpath is :

```
E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jlib\orai18n.jar;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdc6_g.jar;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Users\JamesPJ\Documents;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jlib;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\jdbc\lib\orai18n.jar;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\jdbc\lib\ocrs12.jar
```

If any one know the solution please help me

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Make sure your database is running. Which one are you using? Did you try all(mysql, sql, oracle) and failed?

Comment: [Causes](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/08/network-adapter-could-not-establish.html)

Comment: I am using oracle. The problem is database was not starts when my system starts. Can have any option to fix it. I want to make the database to start at system startup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using oracle then make sure Oracle Listener is started.

Comment: Thanks. Why the listener was not starting at the system startup. When i start the listener manually it was working....

Comment: @JamesPj - This link may be helpful to you http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10839/strt_stp.htm

Comment: I didn't found solution on that page for windows os.

Comment: @JamesPj - Sorry. I think soulution will be here http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10163_01/ap_net.htm

Answer (score 0):

> The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I think you have network related problem. So at least you have specified database connection endpoint incorrectly or database is down.